# Response is not showing on html after using loop

Tags: angularjs, web-services, loops

This is my code, if i removed loop section then it is showing correct response but when i added this, first time it shows output, which is not correct i.e (showing normal response) it should show proper data corresponding to proper tag, and if i run it again it's not showing any response simply printing the template {{myWelcome}}.

I am not getting whats the error and i put alert to check, first alert is working while running first time but second alert is not and while running for second time, nothing happend no response both alert are not working. I am new in angular so please help me

```
  <h3>{{myWelcome}}</h3>
    <h2>{{array}}</h2>
    <h3>{{statuscode}}</h3>
    <h2>{{statustext}}</h2>
 </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost:8086/DashboardMetricsRestService/rest/dashboardmetrics?Purpose=dashBoard"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
          load = response.data; 
          alert(load); // first time it works but for second time, nothing happend


                var tempArray= new Array();
                var res = load.split(",");
                //alert("res length::"+res.length);
                //alert("res ::"+res);

                for(var i=0;i<res.length;i++){

                    if(i==0){
                        var tempData = res[i].substring(1, res[i].length);
                        tempArray.push(tempData);
                    }
                    else if(i==res.length-1){
                        var tempData = res[i].substring(0, res[i].length-1);
                        tempArray.push(tempData);
                    }
                    else{
                        tempArray.push(res[i]);
                    }


          alert("after loop>>>>>" +tempArray); // it is not working first time

          $scope.myWelcome = load;
          $scope.array = tempArray;
          $scope.statuscode = response.status;
          $scope.statustext = response.statusText;

        }, function myError(response) {
          $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you create some jsFiddle and share your code, Instead of URL get to get it work you can create a JSON object and send sample using JS Fiddle,  this helps to debug your issue.

Comment: you forgot the closing bracket of the `for` at the end of the last `else` block